# Why does .NET's regex engine behave so bizarrely when I omit the "else" from a conditional group?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Code:

```
Match match = Regex.Match("abc", "(?(x)bx)");
Console.WriteLine("Success: {0}", match.Success);
Console.WriteLine("Value: \"{0}\"", match.Value);
Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}", match.Index);
```

Output:

```
Success: True
Value: ""
Index: 1
```

It seems that a conditional group without an "else" expression will instead create a lookahead from the first character of the "if" expression and use that as the "else". In this case it would run as if the regex was `(?(x)bx|(?=b))`

What the **** is going on here? Is this intentional? It doesn't seem to be documented.

Edit: An issue has been created in the corefx repository: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26787

Comment: It's a bug .. .. `(?=x)bx` will never match, conditionally it could never be true.

Comment: As the docs, there has to be a `no` clause, and evaluation expression has to be part of the `yes` clause, but the code here is non-conformant, so you cannot anything solid. I tried to check various conditions, and could not get a proper pattern of how this non-conformant code works. This is the same as what Damien mentions in the answer.

Comment: But again, the question is also, why does not the Library throw exception because of this non-conformant expression, like when you miss a bracket or so.

Comment: Just an added note here. I would _not_ recommend letting Dot-Net engine decide if it is an _expressional_ condition or a capture condition. Always be explicit `(?(<named>)` or `(?(?!expression))`.

Comment: Also, this is not just a problem with expression conditionals. The same behavior is with _named/numbered_ group conditionals. [(?(1)ab)(.)](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%281%29ab%29%28.%29&i=ab) as opposed to the correct behavior (anticipated) [(?(1)b|)(.)](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%281%29b%7c%29%28.%29&i=xy)

Comment: @sln .NET does not support `(?(<name>)...)` syntax. Also, implicit and explicit lookaheads have subtle differences, so there may be good situations for one over the other.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why .NET would have ambiguous syntax like that. Just have to wait and see if they do anything from that ticket.

Comment: @KendallFrey instead of `(?(<name>)..)` you could use something like `(?(?<=\k<name>)...)` instead (not that readable, though)

Comment: @WolfgangKluge That means something entirely different. It needs to actually match the capture, rather than just seeing if there was a capture.

Comment: @KendallFrey you're right, sorry

Answer (score 3):

I think it may be a mis-optimization. As [Alternation Constructs in Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/alternation-constructs-in-regular-expressions#conditional-matching-with-an-expression) points out:

> Because the regular expression engine interprets *expression* as an anchor (a zero-width assertion), *expression* must either be a zero-width assertion (for more information, see [Anchors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions)) or a subexpression that is also contained in *yes*.

Your expression value satisfies neither of these constraints. I suspect some form of optimization where, since the expression isn't zero-width the input is advanced until the *yes* can potentially be satisfied (since that's the only pattern you've given the regex engine to work with)

As pointed out in the comments, since your *expression* isn't also contained in *yes*, the pattern can never match and so it's unlikely too much concern would be raised about the mis-optimization.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. (+1)

Comment: This bug has absolutely nothing to do with anything you mention here. You've highlighted a sentence. All that says is if a non-numeric, named capture group is undefined _anywhere_, it is treated as a lookahead assertion, which can  be partially matched _yes_, `(?(xxx).)`, or not at all. Also, the _same_ behavior is exhibited with a named capture `(?(t)(?!)[^rt])(?<t>.)`. Also, advancing the match position has nothing to do with this. Finally, there has never been a requirement for the alternation, never. And what in the world does this `mis-optimization` mean ??

Comment: @sln - by mis-optimization, I mean that they've applied some form of optimization based on assuming that they'll only ever be working with *satisfiable* conditions. I agree that it's a bug, but due to the non-satisfiability of the situation, one that's unlikely to be a high priority.

Comment: `but due to the non-satisfiability of the situation, one that's unlikely to be a high priority` I extremely _doubt_ that muddled (bug) of conditional alternations will not be a high priority given the high usage of stack checking via conditionals (?(x)(?!)typo). It's more likely that MS won't change because it's just a company that sucks. Might as well be honest. After 15 years of MFC I can tell you flat out they suck !!